# yii2 popover и ajax

Tags: yii2, popover

в блоке выводятся некие данные, и у каждого есть кнопка удалить
и троеточие по клике на которое вызывается popover.
Проблема в следующем - удаление делается через ajax, естественно перестраивается структура и т.д. И после построения новой структуры она возвращается из ajax и заносится в блок, так вот в этом случае перестает работать popover, наверняка его нужно переинициировать, кто знает как?

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом

Comment: Я удалил тот код, сделал свои подсазки на Jquery. Решил что сутки на popover сильно долго. Вот часть кода где я пытался притулить popover.
                        <input id="todo_check<?php echo $id?>" onchange="change_todo_check(<?php echo $id?>)" type="checkbox" <?php echo $flg_check?>>
                            <span class="todo_text">
                                <?php echo $komm?>...
                              
                                <br />
                                <span class="opacity-50 fs14"><?php echo $dt ?></span>
                            </span>

Comment: там, где троеточие я хотел выводить popover с остальным текстом, который не влез

Comment: Это код из vew я не смог прикрутить к нему popover